# Methods calls not in sequence, takes some delay to call the first method than the second method in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delay

I have call two methods in a button action,

```
- (IBAction)capture:(id)sender
{

         /*1*/   [self.capturingWindow capturePhoto]; //capture pictures and pass the paths to imagePathsArray

            NSLog(@"imagePathsArray.count---%d",imagePathsArray.count) ;
         /*2*/    [self displayImagesOnScrollView:imagePathsArray];
}
```

I have these two methods in the image capture button.

```
1. [self.capturingWindow capturePhoto]; //capture pictures and pass the paths to imagePathsArray
```

this method capture images and populate the paths of captured images to imagePathsArray

```
 2. [self displayImagesOnScrollView:imagePathsArray];
```

This method using these populated imagePathsArray,

display the images in respective image views..

the problem is **method:1**. `[self.capturingWindow capturePhoto];`  takes some time to capture and load the paths to imagesPathsArray.

in the mean while **method:2**. `[self displayImagesOnScrollView:imagePathsArray];` fires so that as a result crashes happens due to the array beyond bounds.

I tried with

```
 [ self performSelector:@selector(displayImages) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]
```

instead of directly uses the method..

Still no use // it reduce the issue by 40% but still it reproduces

i want that the second method needs to call only after the first method.

But better to maintain less delay (low priority)

Comment: what does the capturePhoto look like?  I would assume if you are using the UIImagePickerController. If that is the case you need to use the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to know when the picture is completed. Then you can call the second method.

Comment: It appears as though capturePhoto is an asynchronous method. You'll want to implement a delegate that fires after capturePhoto has done it's thing instead of trying to use it immediately.

Comment: can you show us the declaration of  `imagePathsArray`

Comment: in viewdidload declrae array and in a delegate method pass the contet to array  imagePathsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [imagePathsArray addObject: imagePathString];

Comment: Thomas Ingham is right. And while you're waiting for the delegate method's invokation, just show the empty table (or fill it with some static data); and when the array is ready, just reload your scrollView with the actual data

Answer (score 0):

This sort of occurrence is fairly common in multi-threaded applications. When code can get executed in multiple threads, you cannot depend on their order in code to be the order they are executed. It seems highly likely your `capturePhoto` doing some of it's work on a background thread.

So, how to we solve that problem? Callbacks and Notifications mainly.

**Callback** - This is where you assign a `delegate` and whenever an important step occurs, the delegate gets a pre-defined method call. A good example of this would be `NSURLConnection` and the `NSURLConnectionDelegate`.

**Notification** - This is when a piece of code broadcasts a message when certain events occur. Other objects which wish to know about the events register with a notification center to receive these broadcasts when the occur. These objects have to register for these notifications before they are sent. For these you'll probably be using the `NSNotificationCenter` and registering for existing notifications like `applicationDidBecomeActive` or even listening for notifications you create and "post."

**Which one should I use?** While you could probably force either one to work in any situation, there are certain times when one or the other will consistently be easier/better/more functional than the other.

- If you have several objects which want to be informed when something happens, you'll probably want a notification.
- If the same message can come from different locations, you'll probably want a notification.
- If one object and only one object needs to know about the timing of when events occur on a different object, you'll often want a callback.

Back to the question at hand though. For your array to be populated, you'll need to create a callback or notification system so `capturePhoto` can tell you when the array has data in it. At that point you can start using the array. Until then you'll need to either display placeholder data or possibly a loading spinner.